# Package openssh-client=1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.7 not found

Tags: 14.04, apt, openssh

I am trying yo install openssh-client=1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.7 by running 
`apt-get install openssh-client=1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.7` but its complaining

```
Version '1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.7' for 'openssh-client' was not found
```

DO I need any repo for this package ?

Answer (score 1):

first you have to check this package version available in repository or not using command :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-cache policy openssh-client

openssh-client:
  Installed: 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8
  Candidate: 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8
  Version table:
 *** 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:6.6p1-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

if this package available then you can install using this command :

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client=1:6.6p1-2ubuntu1

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  ssh-askpass libpam-ssh keychain monkeysphere
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  openssh-server
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  openssh-client
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 1 to remove and 98 not upgraded.
Need to get 566 kB of archives.
After this operation, 961 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
```

if not available then you have to add that repository and then update cache

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then install

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client=1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.7
```

OR

you can download `.deb` of required version and install using `dpkg`

```
sudo dpkg -i package
```

**EDIT :**

it seems that package version `1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.7` is not available in repository. you can install `1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8` using

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client=1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8
```

you can check available package version in [repository](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssh/) or [Here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/openssh-client)